# Parsing XML data with colon from Windows Phone Store

Tags: c#, xml, windows-phone-7

I am taking app details from the Windows Phone Store which throws an XML similar to this:
http://marketplaceedgeservice.windowsphone.com/v8/catalog/apps/e80ab889-bef4-415e-bc92-b4c1c59c0249?os=8.0.9903.0&cc=PH&lang=en-US

My code looks like this:

```
XElement app = XElement.Parse(e.Result);
var y = app.Descendants(XName.Get("feed", "http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom")).First();
```

I am trying to get the value for "image" but can't proceed because of the XML tag with colon a:feed.  I've read about XML namespaces so I tried using XName, using the URL found in the XML tag but it still does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
XNamespace ns = "http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom";
var feed = XDocument.Parse(e.Result).Descendants(ns + "feed").First();
```

**EDIT**

```
XNamespace defns = "http://schemas.zune.net/catalog/apps/2008/02";
var image = XDocument.Parse(e.Result).Descendants(defns + "image").First();
```

Comment: How do I get the value of image?  If I use

    icon=feed.Descendants("image").First().Descendants("id").First().
        Value.ToString();

It throws an InvalidOperationException

Comment: It works, thank you.  I used

var image = XDocument.Parse(e.Result).Descendants(defns + "image").First().Descendants(defns + "id").First().Value;

to get the value of id, which is the one I really need.  If you don't mind, why do you have to use "http://schemas.zune.net/catalog/apps/2008/02" instead when the XML tag for <image> does not contain "xmlns."  I'm not really new to XML, but this is the first time I've been really challenged in parsing XML.  While I really prefer XML over JSON because of (human) readability, I am now starting to appreciate JSON.

Answer (score 0):

This should work...

`XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xmlstring)
var node = from imagenode in doc.Root.Elements()
           where imagenode.Name.LocalName.Equals("image")
           select imagenode;`

Comment: It returns System.Linq.Enumerable when I get the use node.ToString().

Comment: It's because it gets all the images

Comment: Yes that's right. If for example you want to get the value of the first, you can use node.First().Value or node.ElementAt(0).Value